# Sum of rows with multiple conditions in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to do a summary of rows based on certain column conditions. 
There's a table with the following columns:

```
ID# (row #) 
Part
Customer 
Job 
QTY 
Dept 
Pass/Fail
```

Where `ID#` can possibly be the only unique value.

From the table the following needs to be obtained:

1. Need to return All jobs.
2. Need to return all new jobs, which should be all jobs minus any duplicates (i.e., the first entry for each unique Part-Customer-Job-QTY-Dept (i.e., where all 5-values are equal).
3. All Repeat jobs, which should be all ID#-Part-Customer-Job-QTY-Dept-Pass.

For example:

```
1-Part;Customer;Job; QTY; Dept; Fail
2-Part; Customer; Job; QTY; Dept; Pass
```

Where Part-Customer-Job-QTY-Dept are equal, with 1 failing and 2 passing.

1 and 2 are easy, but 3 is a little tricky.

Should I just find the `ID#`'s (rows) that include a fail prior to a pass.

Can it be done in a single loop?

While I'm here, #2 might be tricky as well. Is there any easy way to sum, without duplicates?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

The sample data below should return:

```
10 for All

8 for New

2 for Repeats
```

Doing the sample has me thinking if just subtracting New from All will return all repeats.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you actually need to use VBA as the question seems can be solved by default functions.

The key problem here is to identify all the repeating records, of the unique key `Part-Customer-Job-QTY-Dept`. Note that you don't actually need to take care of the `ID` and `Pass/Fail` as these values do not affect your calculation.

Once you know the unique key, you can solve by the following steps:

1. Make a new column concatenates to produce the unique key. `(F1)=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1`
2. For each row, count the appearance of the unique key among the column.`(G1)=countif(F:F,F1)`
3. You can determine the record is duplicating when the count is larger than one, meaning there are multiple lines in the data using the same unique key.`=countif(G:G,">1")`
4. Once you have the Yes/No answer on each row, you simply count the Yes to yield the repeating count, thus the new jobs according to your definition.

This can also be implemented in VBA by the same logic.

Comment: Is it correct to go the VBA route if it's a report that needs to be automated to run weekly and monthly?  So in checking the duplicates there's no need to check Pass/Fail?  It's pretty slick logic! Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how "automated" you are aiming for...like it is different doing "triggered manually in periodic manner" and "triggered by system schedule". IMO Excel VBA is not good for the former, because usually you need to open the file to call the function.

Comment: Most likely it will be "triggered manually in periodic manner" rather than "triggered by system schedule" (though the latter could be considered). The goal is to have the current weekly or monthly report run at the end of each week or month (i.e., when the source file closes). The process has been primarily manual and I'd like to have everything done by a single button if possible. Opening the file to start the process is fine, but it would be good to avoid any other manual steps. Do you think this will require more than a single button (call)? - Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on the output format you want. For easiest(i.e. laziest) approach, I will be like having all the calculation columns prepared, fill in the input columns by pasting, and copy the output cells. In such approach you don't even need the button as all calculations updating cells are automatically triggered by Excel.